# Get value from subprocess output

Tags: python, subprocess, pdftotext

Here is my input:

```
info = subprocess.run(['pdfinfo', 'test.pdf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Here is the output of `info`:

```
b'Title:          Aboriginal Custom Adoption Recognition\r\nAuthor:         
Department of Justice\r\nCreator:        PScript5.dll Version 
5.2.2\r\nProducer:       Acrobat Distiller 10.0.0 (Windows)\r\nCreationDate:     
Wed Feb 20 11:12:48 2013 Eastern Standard Time\r\nModDate:        Wed Feb 20 
11:12:55 2013 Eastern Standard Time\r\nTagged:         no\r\nUserProperties: 
no\r\nSuspects:       no\r\nForm:           none\r\nJavaScript:     
no\r\nPages:          6\r\nEncrypted:      no\r\nPage size:      612 x 792 
pts (letter)\r\nPage rot:       0\r\nFile size:      20059 
bytes\r\nOptimized:      no\r\nPDF version:    1.5\r\n'
```

I am looking to grab the integer value for `Pages:    6` (so the number of pages in the pdf). Is there a way to grab this through subrocess? And if not, any suggestions on how to grab that value consistently if I have a large number of pdfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use regex to grab the integer after `'Pages: '`.

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'^Pages:\s+(\d+)', info.stdout.read().decode('utf-8'), flags=re.MULTILINE)[0])
```

Comment: How do I do a regex on a bytes string though? The `info.stdout.read()` does not work.

Comment: You can use `decode` to convert bytes into a string. In most cases UTF-8 is the encoding. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: This works! `print(re.findall(r'^Pages:\s+(\d+)', info.stdout.decode('utf-8'), flags=re.MULTILINE)[0])` Thank you so much!